# Cannot figure out how to create table to get that same user to have several different values for date and weight

Tags: mysql

I am creating a simple site. The user can register and then save values for his weight in different dates.
I have a hard time to figure out best way to do this.

Comment: This is diary for weight, In addition user choose a date when he measure himself and the measurement itself and save it in the site. Later he can check how much he weight is a specific date.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add additional information; you can update your question. I downvoted this question because it's not clear what you're asking and it shows no research effort. Is your question about your entity model? About user registration? Front-end? If you want users to save values, create a Google Spreadsheet Form. I guess that's not you want, but please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have a "user age weight" table. Now, people's ages may change, but their date of birth doesn't.  I would envision a table such as:

```
create table users (
    user_id int auto_increment primary key,
    date_of_birth date
);

create table usermeasures (
    user_measure_id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int,
    as_of_date date,
    weight numeric(6, 2),
    constraint fk_usermeasures_userid foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id)
);
```

Of course, you can add additional columns to each table as appropriate (name doesn't change, income might).

Comment: Hello Gordon, Thank you for the tips. stupid of me, I didn't explain well.
This is diary for weight, In addition user choose a date when he measure himself and the measurement itself and save it in the site. Later he can check how much he weight is a specific date.